# Can Amazon "auto-detect" content type of a file uploaded into an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

I am uploading files with various extensions into my S3 bucket. Instead of passing the contentType header with each file upload, can S3 detect the file extension and set the content-type metadata for the file itself? I looked everywhere and could not find this....

I have only set the ContentType field in my NodeJS code. I am hoping there is a way S3 can auto-detect this for every uploaded file.